# AndroidAnnotations with Android Studio ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, annotations, android-annotations

I am trying to use Android Annotation with Android Studio, gradle, but it is not working. I get this error:

> > java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myproject.screen.LoadingActivity_"

top level build-gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.3.2'


..

dependencies {

    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

...
}


apt {
    arguments {
        resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
package com.myproject.screen;
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_loading)
public class LoadingActivity extends FragmentActivity
....
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".screen.LoadingActivity_"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

I have tried, CLEAN PROJECT, RE-BUILD, MAKE PROJECT. Nothing seems to work.
Does anyone know a solution, thank you

Comment: try to restart with clear cache

Comment: i thing you should try below solution.

Comment: Can you check the AA log in the generated source director in the build folder?

Answer (score 0):

**@Joolah** check

> gradle console

it will show you the **exact error** red arror will show the point

Answer (score -2):

Your code problem is.

public class LoadingActivity extends FragmentActivity.

class name is **LoadingActivity**

and you pass at manifest.xml

android:name=".screen.**LoadingActivity_**"

remove _ or make class with name LoadingActivity_

Comment: Hi Vishal, according to https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/FirstActivity you have to use the _ if you used Annotation in that Activity. Your solution does not work.

Comment: https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/FirstActivity#finding-the-androidmanife

do you follow this??